# Take object ( dictionary) and string (sentence) as function parameters and return values from adequete keys

Tags: javascript, key, javascript-objects

I have to make a function that takes dictionary (object) and sentence as parameteres and returns adequete key's value and if there is missing word in a dictionary function should throw an error "Error: missing value"

these are examples of output:

translate({
"je": "I",
"suis": "am",
"pere": "father",
"ton": "your"}, "je suis ton pere"
) // 'I am your father'

translate({
"the": "le",
"cute": "mignon",
"your": "ton",
"dog": "chien",
"is": "est"}, "the dog is cute"
) // 'le chien est mignon'

translate({
"the": "le",
"cute": "mignon",
"your": "ton",
"dog": "chien",
"is": "est"}, "the dog is fluffy"
) // 'Error: missing value'

**my code is like that: and its working but it stops at index 0, so i can get only first result which is "I"**

```
let dictionary = {
    "je": "I",
    "suis": "am",
    "pere": "father",
    "ton": "your"
}

let dictKeys = Object.keys(dictionary)

let translated = []


for(let i=0; i < sentence.length; i++){
    for(let j=0; j < dictKeys.length; i++){
        if(sentence[i] == dictKeys[j]){
            translated.push(dictionary[dictKeys[j]])
            console.log(translated)
        }
    }
}
```

i have no idea how to finish this exercise, please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was almost fine. In your second loop, you incremented again i instead of j. I added a toLowerCase to cover case sensitive words

```js
let dictionary = {
  "je": "I",
  "suis": "am",
  "pere": "father",
  "ton": "your"
}

let dictKeys = Object.keys(dictionary)
let translated = []
let missing = []
let sentence = "Je suis ton ami abc gfukgv".split(" ")

for (let i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
  if (!dictKeys.includes(sentence[i].toLowerCase())) {
    missing.push(sentence[i])
    //console.error(`"${sentence[i]}" word is missing from dictionary`)
  }
  for (let j = 0; j < dictKeys.length; j++) {
    if (sentence[i].toLowerCase() == dictKeys[j].toLowerCase()) {
      translated.push(dictionary[dictKeys[j]])
    }
  }
}

missing.length > 0 ? console.error(`The following words are missing from the dictionary: ${missing.join(", ")}`) : null

console.log(translated.join(" "))
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much! Such a small mistake can take so much time to find! I have other question, do you know how to make this function say “error: missing value” if there is word in a sentence that doesn’t match dictionary keys? Like here: translate({ "the": "le", "cute": "mignon", "your": "ton", "dog": "chien", "is": "est"}, "the dog is fluffy" ) // 'Error: missing value'

Comment: I added an if condition that first checks if the word exists in the dictionary. If not, you can either console an error at each iteration or I pushed all the missing words into an array and console an error message at the end with all words missing. You can also use "throw" instead on console.error in the if condition. That will stop the execution as soon as a word is missing.